# Call python machine learning model from UDF or SP

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, python

I would like to run records from my database (Postgres), after an update, through a machine learning model. This model resides in a model.py file.

Next to simply porting the python model over to a SP or UDF (I do not know which *would* be the best to use, if at all).

How might I call this python model and pass the record parameters to the model and return a desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically three options:

1. Have a **program written in Python**, that uses [PsycoPG](http://initd.org/psycopg/), [PyGreSQL](http://www.pygresql.org) or some [other driver with equivalent functionality](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python) to get the data *out* of PostgreSQL and process it in Python.  Or you could use some toolkit like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org), which works as an *Object Relational Mapper*.
2. Write a **User Defined Function using [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html)**, which means you actually write UDFs *within* PostgreSQL using the Python language. If your model works with a certain function `model_predict(a, b, c)`, you can call it in a fashion similar to:

   `SELECT a, b, c, model_predict(a, b, c) AS prediction
      FROM table
     WHERE <condition>`
3. **Export the data** from PostgreSQL (with [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) ..., or using any tool such as [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org)), into a suitable format (such as CSV), and then **import it and process in Python** (you could use [Pandas read csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), e.g.).

Comment: With OPTION #1 - Would PsycoPG/SQLAlchemy need to 'watching' for the changes if it was only to be called ON UPDATE?

Comment: Don't fully understant what you mean to be called "ON UPDATE"... If you have a program to be run _outside_ of the database, it is up to you to decide at which point it should be set to run. If you need to react quickly to **data changes** _within_ the database, I would recommend doing things _within_ the database (via INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE **triggers**). Other solutions to let the _outside_ world know that changes have occurred are possible, via [LISTEN/NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html), or via periodic polling. It takes some learning how to use it.

Comment: Your are correct in assuming I would like to react to changes to the data as quickly as possible. If the trigger were to fire the function when the record is updated, then using PsycoPG to INSERT into another table (storing the predictions). This is the desired functionality. I was not aware of LISTEN/NOTIFY before, thank you for that. As you stated, *within* the database is the nominal option, and I will move forward with that.

Comment: That link does not really describe how to create a `udf` in python. Got any better pointer?